# Do swarmers count towards kill awards in multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In multiplayer, you get bronze, silver and gold [awards](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3_Multiplayer#Individual_Awards) that give you experience. Some of these are for 25, 50 and 75 kills with each gun and in total.

When fighting the Reaper troops, [Swarmers](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Swarmer) will be released from Ravagers when you shoot them.  Does killing these count towards the above awards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Swarmers, like Turrets, do not count towards Kill Awards.

Comment: This answer previously stated that Husk kills did not count towards certain rewards. This is false - the issue is that Throw doesn't count as a biotic kill if an enemy dies due to the physics damage. Husks contribute equally to kill awards like most everything else.